# Binary serialization of variable length data and zero length arrays, is it safe?

Tags: c++, c, serialization

I did some research but cannot find a definite approval or disapproval.

What I want is, a fixed size structure + variable length part, so that serialization can be expressed in simple and less error prone way.

```
struct serialized_data
{
    int len;
    int type;
    char variable_length_text[0];
};
```

And then:

```
serialize_data buff = (serialize_data*)malloc(sizeof(serialize_data)+5);
buff->len=5;
buff->type=1;
memcpy(buff->variable_length_text, "abcd", 5);
```

Unfortunately I can't find if MSVC, GCC, CLang etc., are ok with it.

Maybe there is a better way to achieve the same?

I really don't want those ugly casts all around:

```
memcpy((char*)(((char*)buffer)+sizeof(serialize_data)), "abcd", 5);
```

Comment: That should be `char variable_length_text[1];`, but yes, there is surely a better way to achieve the same.

Comment: Pick a language. Are you interested in C++ or C?

Comment: You will probably find this article useful. Doesn't answer the portability question but does give some insight into this pattern http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx

Comment: @ildjarn shouldn't the 0 length array be legal as of C99?

Comment: @JaredPar : Yes, but this is tagged `c++` as well.

Comment: No, `char variable_length_text[1];` reserves 1 byte of memory inside structure, `[0]` does not.

Comment: @ildjarn oh, so C++ doesn't allow for 0 length arrays? Sorry, not very up to date on the C++ spec.

Comment: It's a C++ project, but I need to use POD data.

Comment: @JaredPar: Zero-length arrays are not permitted in C99.  You're thinking of *flexible array members*, defined without a length like `char member[];`.  They must occur as the last member in a `struct`, and they're only permitted in C99.  Not all compilers (notable MSVC) are C99-compliant, so it's more portable to use a 1-length array, although that complicates size calculations.

Comment: The 0 should be rejected (or, at least, warned about in any standard-compliant mode of compilation).  Use a 1 instead of the 0 and you're dealing with the 'struct hack' (search term).  C99 has 'flexible array members' which would work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program is using a zero length array. This is not C but a GNU extension.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

A common idiom in C89, called the *struct hack*, was to use:

```
struct serialized_data
{
    int len;
    int type;
    char variable_length_text[1];
};
```

Unfortunately its common use as a flexible array is not strictly conforming.

C99 comes with something similar to perform the same task: a feature called the *flexible array member*.
Here is an example right from the Standard (C99, 6.7.2.1p17)

```
struct s { int n; double d[]; };
int m = 12;  // some value
struct s *p = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + sizeof (double [m]));
```

Comment: Can I use C99 way and be safe that it will work on MSVC7/8/9, GCC and Clang?

Comment: C99 is supported by gcc and clang but not by MSVC. The struct hack although not strictly conforming is pretty common and should be considered for C89 compilers.